# How do i find length of the array in Mongoose aggregation

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am doing Lookup the two collections in mongoose:

My first collection :[Folder]

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("00000000c27b9d0d045ff376"),
    "folder_name" : "Testing 2",
    "status" : "Y",
  "parent_id" : [ 
        ObjectId("00000000666e6e2084393a11")
    ],
    "created_date" : ISODate("2018-07-24T15:10:38.456+05:30"),
    "updated_date" : ISODate("2018-07-24T15:10:38.456+05:30")
}
```

My second Collection : [inspection]

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b55bb043f37a8f292e1ada2"),
    "project_id" : ObjectId("00000000666e6e2084393a11"),
    "inspection_data" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b3b3aa86b20153284d45a54"),
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b3b3aa86b20153284d45a54"),

        }
    ]
}
```

My lookup query

```
mongo.folder.aggregate([

                {
                    $lookup:
                    {
                        from: 'inspections',
                        localField: '_id',
                        foreignField: 'project_id',
                        as: 'projectdata'
                    }

                },


                       { $match : {
                    $and: [ 
                         {'parent_id': ObjectId(req.body.folder_id)}, 

                    ]

               }
            },
                {
                    "$project": {
                        "_id" : 0
                        "inspection_count" {$size:"$projectdata.inspection_data"}

                    }
                }

            ]).exec(function (err, response) {
                console.log(response) // It should show inspection count as 2 but its showing 1
            })
```

If I am doing unwind for project data means am getting one data only .Is any other way to do this

Comment: Can you show sample of the expected result?

Comment: Inspection count should be 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$lookup` returns an array. Something like

```
{"projectdata":[{... "inspection_data" : [{},{}]}]}
```

So `projectdata.inspection_data` ia array of arrays i.e `[[{},{}]]` and size is 1.
 Use [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) with index 0 to access inner array followed by [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) return the the length of inspection_data.

```
"inspection_count" {"$size":{"$arrayElemAt":["$projectdata.inspection_data",0]}}
```

Comment: "inspection_count" : {$size: {"$ifNull":[{$arrayElemAt:["$projectdata.inspection_data",0]},[] ] } }

I have used $ifNull because am having 3 data's 2 data's are null .. Thank you so much

Comment: And this one also works fine :

 "inspection_count" :{$size:{$reduce: {
                             input: "$projectdata.inspection_data",
                             initialValue: [ ],
                             in: { $concatArrays : ["$$value", "$$this"] }
                         }}}